# Best way to rotate elements of an array while preserving the consistency of the elements' id

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects:

```
var array = [
    { some_id: 0, name:'a' },
    { some_id: 1, name:'b' },
    { some_id: 2, name:'c' },
    { some_id: 3, name:'d' },
    { some_id: 4, name:'e' },
    { some_id: 5, name:'f' }
];
```

What is the best way to move object of `some_id = 4` to the position `some_id = 1` while updating the `some_id` values of the elements that are moved such that the order of `some_id` values in the array remains the same after the transformation?

For example, after moving `some_id = 4` to `some_id = 1` you get:

```
array = [
    { some_id: 0, name:'a' },
    { some_id: 1, name:'e' },
    { some_id: 2, name:'b' },
    { some_id: 3, name:'c' },
    { some_id: 4, name:'d' },
    { some_id: 5, name:'f' }
];
```

Essentially what should happen is:

1. We move `{ some_id: 4, name:'e' }` to `{ some_id: 1, name:'e' }`.
2. We move `{ some_id: 1, name:'b' }` to `{ some_id: 2, name:'b' }`.
3. We move `{ some_id: 2, name:'c' }` to `{ some_id: 3, name:'c' }`.
4. We move `{ some_id: 3, name:'d' }` to `{ some_id: 4, name:'d' }`.

Hence, we are just rotating elements and changing the `some_id` value. Note that we don't touch any other property of the object.

Comment: "the best" way using what comparison criteria?

Comment: Its really not a valid array

Comment: `var o = arr[arr[4].index = 1]; arr[1] = arr[arr[1].index = 4], arr[4] = o;` should do. Or try `arr.splice(arr[4].index=1, 1, arr.splice(4, 1, a[1])[0]).index = 4;`

Comment: @zerkms please tell me if my added edits help you

Comment: That's not swapping. That's removing and reinserting.

Comment: Why are you creating an array of objects with an `index` property when the array itself has an index for each element?

Comment: @AaditMShah sorry index is poorly named and it is not meant to reflect the position inside an array

Comment: You ask "What's the best way to move object of `some_id = 4` into position `1` while updating `some_id` values". If `some_id` does not reflect the index position of the element in the array then you first need to find the object with `some_id = 4` which will take `O(n)` time instead of `O(1)` because of no random access. In addition, you'll also need to find the object with `some_id = 1` so that you can insert another element in its place. In total, you'll need two loops. The first loop finds the objects with `some_id = 4` and `some_id = 1` and the second loop rearranges the elements.

Comment: @AaditMShah how would would second, rearranging, loop look?

Answer (score 1):

The “best” way that I can think of “dragging and dropping elements while updating the element identifiers” is as follows:

```js
function move(key, src, to, array)                                              {
    var length   = array.length
    if (length === 0) return array
    var srcIndex = -1
    var toIndex  = -1
    var index    = 0

    loop: do switch (array[index][key])                                         {
        case src: srcIndex = index++; break loop
        case to:  toIndex  = index++; break loop                                }
    while (++index < length)

    if (index === length) return array

    if (srcIndex < 0) do if (array[index][key] === src)                         {
            srcIndex = index; break                                             }
        while (++index < length)
    else do if (array[index][key] === to)                                       {
            toIndex  = index; break                                             }
        while (++index < length)

    if (index === length) return array

    var step = toIndex < srcIndex ? 1 : -1
        src  = array[srcIndex]

    do                                                                          {
        to   = array[toIndex]
        array[toIndex] = src
        src[key] = toIndex
        toIndex += step
        src = to                                                                }
    while (toIndex !== srcIndex)

    array[toIndex] = src
    src[key] = toIndex
    return array                                                                }
```

```html
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
    var array = [
        { some_id: 0, name: 'a' },
        { some_id: 1, name: 'b' },
        { some_id: 2, name: 'c' },
        { some_id: 3, name: 'd' },
        { some_id: 4, name: 'e' },
        { some_id: 5, name: 'f' }
    ];

    print(move("some_id", 4, 1, array));

    print(move("some_id", 1, 4, array));

    function print(array) {
        alert("[\n" + array.map(function (obj) {
            return "    { some_id: " + obj.some_id +
                ", name: '" + obj.name + "' }";
        }).join(",\n") + "\n]");
    }
}, 0);
</script>
```

This is what I am doing:

1. The first `loop` finds either the `srcIndex` or the `toIndex`, whichever one comes first.
2. If we find either `srcIndex` or `toIndex` and if it is not the last index of `array` (which means that we may find the other index as well) then we continue. Otherwise we return `array`.
3. We check which index is still not found and we loop through the remaining elements to find it.
4. If we can't find the second index then we return `array`. Otherwise we continue.
5. Now that we have the two indices, we can simply rearrange the elements in the final loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Alnitak I removed the semicolons to make it more beautiful... ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;. 25 semicolons for you.

Comment: Thanks.  The last do...while is the nugget I was looking for.  Not sure what case this line solves though: if (srcIndex < 0) do if (array[index][key] === src).  Can you explain?

Comment: We need to find two indices, the `srcIndex` and the `toIndex`. The first loop finds either the `srcIndex` or the `toIndex` but not both (whichever one comes first). Hence we need a second loop to find the second index (which might be either the `srcIndex` or the `toIndex`). We need to figure out which index it is. Hence we use `srcIndex < 0`. You see, initially we set both `srcIndex` and `toIndex` to `-1`. Hence they are both less than `0`. Now, an index is always `0` or more. Hence if we first found `toIndex`, then `srcIndex` would still be less than `0` and vice versa. That's all it does. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the splice method, which allows you to add/remove elements from an element to an array. To move index 1's element into index 4:

```
element = arr.splice(1, 1);
arr.splice(4, 0, element);
```

You could alternately combine these two into one line:

```
arr.splice(4, 0, arr.splice(1,1));
```

Here's the W3Schools page on the splice method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

As far as updating the id's goes, I'd loop through the array to match the id to the current index (since in your example you're just moving element e and not replacing it with element b):

```
arr.forEach( function(element, index) {
    element.some_id = index;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct output. The `some_id` values are not updated correctly.

Comment: The content of the question changed, this worked for how I understood the original.

Comment: There, I added a way to update the id's after moving an element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified, reformatted version of AaditMShah's answer

```
function move(key, src, to, array) {

    var srcIndex = -1, toIndex  = -1;

    for( var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++ ) {
       switch(array[i][key]) {
           case src: 
              srcIndex = i; 
              break;
           case to: 
              toIndex  = i; 
              break;
       }

       if ( srcIndex > -1 && toIndex > -1 ) {
          break;
       }
    }

    if ( (srcIndex == -1 || toIndex == -1) || (srcIndex == toIndex )
      return array

    var step = toIndex < srcIndex ? 1 : -1
        src  = array[srcIndex]

    do {
        to   = array[toIndex]
        array[toIndex] = src
        src[key] = toIndex
        toIndex += step
        src = to
    } while (toIndex !== srcIndex);

    array[toIndex] = src
    src[key] = toIndex

    return array                                                                
}
```